# Highcharts date tick position hiding removing

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have tried using all sorts of combinations of tickInterval, tickPixelInterval label formatter and tickPositioner and I haven't been able to solve this issue.

I have a chart builder that pulls in different feeds and allows the user to modify the date range of those feeds before shooting this data into highcharts and spitting out the chart.

The problem is that some of the time, the first and/or last dates get cut off. Here is an example:[image: July is cut off]

Without adjusting the margins of the chart (which causes the chart to take up less space), how do I prevent this from happening?

If I was able to determine the pixel location of the ticks and their labels, I could in theory, hide the specific ticks and their corresponding labels which were located outside the graph / cut off. Thoughts?

Comment: It would help to see your highcharts options.

Comment: share this on jsfiddle please

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code - there are a few things you can do.

1. [Rotate your labels](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels/grid)
2. [Play around with the x/y axis labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.x)
3. [Align them to the right](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.align)

Hopefully one of these would help your cause.